# Why does SKVideoNode automatically starts playing video on iOS9?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios9, skvideonode

When initialising a `SKVideoNode` with a video URL in `iOS9` the behaviour changed to automatically starting the video as soon as the node is added, i.s.o. after the play method is called in previous versions of `iOS`.

doing the following inside the `SKScene init`

```
SKVideoNode* videoNode = [SKVideoNode videoNodeWithVideoFileNamed:@"sample.m4v"];
[self addChild:videoNode];
```

is enough to see the video playing, while previous iOS versions (more logically) required to also call

```
[videoNode play];
```

before the video starts playing.

Is this an intended change? A possible workaround I see is always immediately calling `pause` after initialising a video but it's a bit weird this behaviour changed.
(it feels like a bug to be honest)

(I also found the iOS9 simulator to have issues with SKVideoNodes playing at all, you have to test this on a device)

Comment: I've found a workaround, subclass `SKVideoNode` and its method `- (void)setPaused:(BOOL)paused`, check `[NSThread callStackSymbols]` to see if it's from your class, if yes, call `[super setPaused:paused]`.

Comment: Same problem here... Also, `pause` and `isPaused` seem to be out of sync for me. I've never worked with iOS video APIs before but this and `MPMoviePlayerController` / `AVPlayer` are the worst APIs I've worked with so far (iOS-wise).